# Gatekeeper scanning files opened over SMB share

Tags: smb, gatekeeper

I am working with a client that has been experiencing poor performance with large files over SMB.  There are a lot of pieces to this puzzle, but I have one in particular here I could use some help with.

The environment hass several users, all with higher end iMacs, editing large Photoshop files (PSD and PSB) that reside on a Windows 10 PRO SMB share.  Often we have been seeing Gatekeeper pop up and 'verify' these files which takes some time.  I have done a bit of googling, and have not seen where this is a normal behavior of Gatekeeper.  My understanding is that it scans files with certain extended attributes which should not be present on an SMB mount (I verified this with xattr).

Has anyone seen this?  We could turn Gatekeeper off, but that feels like a poor solution.  They have 3rd party AV/malware protection so it would not be extremely risky, and may improve performance in other with reduced resource contention, but I would like to know how/why gatekeeper appears to be doing this.